# How is wifi used to detect network location?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, geolocation, gps, network-location

On my iPhone, when WiFi is turned off and I use GPS/Navigation apps, the phone suggests that I should turn on WiFi for improved location accuracy. If I have WiFi turned on and am not connected to a network, this message doesn't appear.

How's the mere turning on of WiFi radio helping estimate my location? I can understand how it works with the network radios (cell towers, triangulation etc.) but how does the WiFi radio help?

Answer (score 2):

Google, Microsoft, and Apple use parts of their core mobile operating system to collect SSID location information and can use that to estimate your location. In other words, they use YOU to map where you, or more specifically your mobile device and everyone else's mobile device, to maintain a world wide database of SSID and relative strengths and GPS positioning... then by referencing what SSID are visible and approximate strengths for those SSIDs, your position can be approximated by triangulation.

http://www.zdnet.com/article/how-google-and-everyone-else-gets-wi-fi-location-data/

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to keep it simplified. Every router puts off a beacon. This beacon contains unique identifiable information, namely the MAC address of the broadcasting device.

Now assume there are a billion people with phones and their phone's software asks to use wifi to improve GPS. What do you think is happening? Well if billions of people have this feature enabled we can assume that any wireless router they drive by is scanned, logged, and uploaded to a server where that data can be tweaked and compared with other data and create a mapping system of where routers are located. Since most routers have a range of 30-100 meters this can be used to help narrow down a range. On top of that, your phone also gets a signal strength from the beacon. Even more, you can also see other wireless devices, including cell phones, with their signal strength. This can all be used and be converted to an actual lat/long position and therefore would supplement actual GPS satellite numbers. This means faster results on your GPS and a little better accuracy.